# Add a font face css in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

fabricjs can change the font of a text in a canvas to a font family. For that the font needs to exist in the browser, either CSS or emb link.

I now want to add dynamically a font from a resource (google, self hosted ect) to the css populating it in the document via @font-face. I don't want to just list all fonts in the css beforehand because it can be a huge list. Is it possible to modify the running css in reactjs to add a font face to it?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS-in-JS solutions like [emotion](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion), [styled component](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) or [radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium)